# VBA Dataform Value

Tags: excel, vba

Hi i have 2 worksheets and using one as a form and one as a data sheet

```
 Dim DataWks As Worksheet
 Dim InputWks As Worksheet

 Set InputWks = Worksheets("Sheet3")
 Set DataWks = Worksheets("Sheet1")
```

On the form sheet - InputWks it has an oleobject called tbRiskContext

I want the value of this to be placed in the Datawks - Datasheet in a Range called Database
in cell (2,2)

I can put a value in the range by doing

```
ActiveSheet.Range("DataBase").Cells(2, 2) = "it works"
```

but how do i get the value from the oleobject to go in Cell(2,2)

Any idea?

Comment: You are neglecting to mark your questions as solved.  I have answered two of your questions which you have left hanging.  Sort these out and you may find you get more help. :)

Comment: Apologies i just discovered the large tick on the question page. I never hovered over the symbols until just now and saw their purpose. I have marked both as accepted. Sorry mate. I cant upvote till my reputation is 15 - sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
With DataWks
   .Cells(2, 2) = InputWks.OLEObjects("tbRiskContext").Object.Value
End With
```